# Find PCI configuration

Tags: ubuntu, pci

In [this page](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/dd/pci.html), Figure 6.1 shows an example of PCI configuration, with two buses.

Using Linux (Ubuntu), is it possible to get the PCI configuration of the actual motherboard? I mean: determine how many PCI buses are present, find if there is a PCI-express bus and the bridges, so that one can draw a diagram similar to that Figure 6.1.

`lspci` gives a list of the PCI devices, but it does not seem to explicitly show the connections and the buses structure.

Comment: `lspci -t` is a bit more structured.

Comment: @meuh yes, but it still doesn't tell about the type of bus (PCI, PCI-express, ISA, ...)

Comment: Have you looked if exploring `/sys/bus/pci/devices` gives all the information you want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dmidecode` and `lshw` together provide a reasonable picture. `dmidecode`, on a correctly-configured system (*i.e.* one with correctly-populated DMI tables), will list physical slots and their characteristics. For example, on my system, I see information such as

```
Handle 0x001C, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: SLOT7 PCI-E 2.0 X 1
        Type: x1 PCI Express
        Current Usage: In Use
        Length: Short
        ID: 0
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                Opening is shared
                PME signal is supported
        Bus Address: 0000:07:00.0
```

and

```
Handle 0x0021, DMI type 9, 17 bytes
System Slot Information
        Designation: SLOT1 PCI 33MHz
        Type: 32-bit PCI
        Current Usage: In Use
        Length: Short
        ID: 5
        Characteristics:
                3.3 V is provided
                Opening is shared
                PME signal is supported
        Bus Address: 0000:09:00.0
```

The designations can be quite detailed; on this particular board the physical slots and electrical capabilities are correctly identified (*e.g.* `PCI-E 3.0 X8 (IN X16)`).

`lshw` indicates the bridge connections, and its information can be matched with `dmidecode`'s using the bus addresses. This allows motherboard-hosted bridges to be distinguished from adapter-hosted bridges. (For example, one of my systems has two PCI slots on a C226 motherboard, using a PCI bridge on the motherboard; it also has an ATTO SCSI PCI Express HBA which uses two PCI-hosted chips behind another PCI bridge, on the card itself. `lshw`'s output doesn't make it easy to distinguish the two cases, but combined with `dmidecode`'s output it's obvious which is which.)